# Bug with Python UTF-16 output and Windows line endings?

Tags: python, windows, utf-16

With this code:

**test.py**

```
import sys
import codecs

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-16')(sys.stdout)

print "test1"
print "test2"
```

Then I run it as:

```
test.py > test.txt
```

In Python 2.6 on Windows 2000, I'm finding that the newline characters are being output as the byte sequence **`\x0D\x0A\x00`** which of course is wrong for UTF-16.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug?

Comment: Under Mac OS X it works fine: "fe ff 00" are the first three bytes.

Comment: Interesting information but I don't see how it's relevant to the question. I imagine that this issue is only significant for platforms with Windows-style (CR-LF) line endings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys
import codecs

if sys.platform == "win32":
    import os, msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)

class CRLFWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, output):
        self.output = output

    def write(self, s):
        self.output.write(s.replace("\n", "\r\n"))

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return getattr(self.output, key)

sys.stdout = CRLFWrapper(codecs.getwriter('utf-16')(sys.stdout))
print "test1"
print "test2"
```

Comment: Looks great. Which leads to two points: 1) can Python support chaining of codecs? 2) if yes, then I suggest Python should provide a codec to deal with line ending conversion and deprecate the use of low-level "binary vs text" file I/O.

Comment: Well, CRLF line endings are supposed to be transparent when you open a file in non-binary mode.  The reason it's breaking here is because it's designed only for byte stream files, not for word streams like UTF-16.  To handle that, it'd need to define some way to tell the file which type it is.  I think that just doesn't fit the file design, and I suspect the use case of outputting UTF-16 is too uncommon to jump those hoops to accomodate it automatically.

Answer (score 3):

The newline translation is happening inside the stdout file.  You're writing "test1\n" to sys.stdout (a StreamWriter).  StreamWriter translates this to "t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x001\x00\n\x00", and sends it to the real file, the original sys.stderr.

That file doesn't know that you've converted the data to UTF-16; all it knows is that any \n values in the output stream need to be converted to \x0D\x0A, which results in the output you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks, that's insightful and points me in the right direction.

Comment: I found this Python documentation for codecs.open():
http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.open
which says "Note: Files are always opened in binary mode, even if no binary mode was specified. This is done to avoid data loss due to encodings using 8-bit values. This means that no automatic conversion of '\n' is done on reading and writing."

I guess that means this combination of encoding and line-ending translation is hard to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

I've found two solutions so far, but not one that gives output of UTF-16 **with** Windows-style line endings.

First, to redirect Python **`print`** statements to a file with UTF-16 encoding (output Unix style line-endings):

```
import sys
import codecs

sys.stdout = codecs.open("outputfile.txt", "w", encoding="utf16")

print "test1"
print "test2"
```

Second, to redirect to **`stdout`** with UTF-16 encoding, without line-ending translation corruption (output Unix style line-endings) (thanks to [this ActiveState recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65443/)):

```
import sys
import codecs

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-16')(sys.stdout)

if sys.platform == "win32":
    import os, msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)

print "test1"
print "test2"
```