# How to extract a file temporarily from a zip file with python 3.5

Tags: python, xml, io, zip, python-3.5

I'm trying to parse through the lines of a file that has been zipped.  My test prints are showing that the first line is all binary.  I would like this to not be the case, but I don't want to have to create a file on any HDD, I'd like to temporarily extract (file exists in memory) to use for parsing and then close it.  There are a lot of small files in a lot of zip files that I only need briefly and writing any amount to the HDD will just junk things up, so writing to the drive isn't a good solution for me.

```
ListOfZipFiles = os.listdir(AllFileLocation)
i=0
for zipIndex in ListOfZipFiles:
    strIndex=ListOfZipFiles[i].find("_")
    if strIndex > 0:
        #Next line gets the date from the file name in the format saved
        FileDate=datetime.strptime(ListOfZipFiles[i][0:strIndex],"%Y-%m-%d")
        if FileDate >= StartTimeFrame and FileDate < EndingTimeFrame:
            print(AllFileLocation + "\\" + ListOfZipFiles[i])
            Zip = zipfile.ZipFile(AllFileLocation + "\\" + ListOfZipFiles[i],"r")
            FileList=Zip.namelist()
            j=0
            for fileIndex in FileList:
                print(FileList[j])
                WorkFile=Zip.open(FileList[j],"r")
                Data=WorkFile.read()
                WorkFile.close()
                LineList=Data.splitlines()

                #Determine if this is a result for our target
                k=0
                PodProjectLine=0
                for lineIndex in LineList:
                    print(BytesIO(LineList[k]))
                    if PodProjectIndentifier in BytesIO(LineList[k]):
                        PodProjectLine=k
                        lineIndex=len(LineList)
                    k+=1

                if PodProjectLine==0:
                    #shit happened, handle it
                    print("PodProjectLine=0, this should not happen.")
                else:
                    match=re.search(PodProjectIndentifier,LineList[PodProjectLine])
                    PodProjectStart=match.end(1)
                    match=re.search(AttributeLineEnder,LineList[PodProjectLine])
                    PodProjectEnd=match.start(1)
                    PodProject=LineList[PodProjectStart:PodProjectEnd]
                    print(PodProject)
                j+=1
    i+=1
```

I had been having an error on the line of "BytesIO(LineList[k])" until I included BytesIO.  I feel like this is nearly what I need, but what I'm seeing from "print(BytesIO(LineList[k]))" is binary and I want to see text.  I suspect the issue is with "WorkFile=Zip.open(FileList[j],"r")" but I don't know.  I'm seeing the first line of the file as:

```
b'\xff\xfe<\x00?\x00x\x00m\x00l\x00 \x00v\x00e\x00r\x00s\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00=\x00"\x001\x00.\x000\x00"\x00 \x00e\x00n\x00c\x00o\x00d\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00=\x00"\x00u\x00t\x00f\x00-\x001\x006\x00"\x00?\x00>\x00'
```

When it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `b'...'` in your output string indicates that the output is a byte stream.  To convert it should probably be:

```
print(s.decode('utf-16'))
```

See [Stream/string/bytearray transformations in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197589/stream-string-bytearray-transformations-in-python-3) for details.

Comment: Modified the following to include a new section to decode but I get an error.  `LineList=Data.splitlines()

                StringList=list()
                k=0
                for lineIndex in LineList:
                    StringList.append(LineList[k].decode(EncodingVersion))
                    k+=1

                #Determine if this is a result for our target
                k=0
                PodProjectLine=0
                for lineIndex in StringList:
                    print(StringList[k])`

Comment: Error:  `line 59, in <module>
    StringList.append(LineList[k].decode(EncodingVersion))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x00 in position 0: truncated data`  What does it mean that it can't decode that?  Seems the `Data.splitlines()` is why I have a list of binary items - is there a way to .... Nevermind.  Added `Data=WorkFile.read().decode(EncodingVersion)` and it is now no longer in binary. Thanks.